# Windows Phone runtime Pivot doesn't react on SelectedIndex change before first user interaction

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I've a Windows Phone RT app that uses `Pivot` element. Now I want to implement a secondary tile, so I need to select the apropriate pivot element during app's initialization.
I try to set pivot element's `SelectedIndex` in `OnNavigatedTo()` method, but the UI doesn't show that change.

Actually I noticed that the `SelectedIndex` itself is changed, but I still see the first pivot item. Ex: imagine I have 3 pivot items. By default the item with index 0 is loaded into Pivot. I programmatically assign `SelectedIndex = 1`. No changes in UI. But when I swipe left, pivot shows me the third pivot item.
Tried using `UpdateLayout()` method with no luck.

Any thougths why this could happen?

Comment: what you are implementing is correct. If this is not working in OnNavigatedTo() event, then try implementing it in Loaded() event of the page. See if this helps. I tried it and it's working.

Comment: Well, it didn't work in `Loaded` too. But I tried to insert `SelectedIndex = 1` before `base.OnNavigatedTo(e)` and it did the trick. It shows me the correct pivot item. But I noticed that in this case I can't change the pivot item by swiping in pivot item content. The only method to change pivot item is to swipe on pivot items' headers. After that I can swipe pivot items as usual.